# Tag dispatching on mixed runtime/compile time condition

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, boost-fusion

I have the following tag dispatching code (see [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/uj8P1%243))

```
#include <iostream>

// traits types
struct A {}; struct B {}; struct C {};

// helpers
void fun_impl(bool, A) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
void fun_impl(bool, B) { std::cout << "B\n"; }

// would like to eliminate this
void fun_impl(bool b, C) 
{ 
  if(b) 
    fun_impl(b, A()); 
  else 
    fun_impl(b, B()); 
}

template<typename T>
void fun(bool b, T t)
{
    // T = A, B, or C
    fun_impl(b, t);        
}

int main()
{
    fun(true,  A()); // "A"
    fun(false, A()); // "A"
    fun(true,  B()); // "B"
    fun(false, B()); // "B"
    fun(true,  C()); // "A"
    fun(false, C()); // "B"
}
```

However, this tag disptatching is closely tied to the function `fun` and I need to maintain 3 helper functions to implement this tag dispatching for every function that uses this.

**Argument deduction fail**: I have tried to abstract the `fun_impl` into a template parameter of a `mixed_dispatch` function object, but if I then pass `fun_impl` as an argument, it cannot be deduced which of the 2 overloads should be required.

```
template<typename T>
struct mixed_dispatch
{
    template<typename Fun>
    void operator()(Fun f, bool b)
    {
        return f(b, T());
    }
};

template<>
struct mixed_dispatch<C>
{
    template<typename Fun>
    void operator()(Fun f, bool b)
    {
        if (b) 
           return f(b, A());
        else
           return f(b, B());
    }
};

template<typename T>
void fun(bool b, T)
{
    // T = A, B, or C
    mixed_dispatch<T>()(fun_impl, b); // ERROR: Fun cannot be deduced   
}
```

**Question**: is there any other way to decouple the tag dispatching from the function being called?

I'm open to any suggestions using C++11 variadic templates / Boost.Fusion or other wizardry that simplifies my current code (I now have to maintain 3 instead of 2 helper functions for every function that uses this specific dispatch, and with more complicated dispatching the number of helper functions grows even faster).

Comment: You can't specify the return type based on the *values* of the arguments.

Comment: @ipc I realize that this cannot be done fully at compile-time, but perhaps some covariant return type trickery or unions could help here?

Comment: Is the value of `b` known at compile time?

Comment: @jrok no, it' a runtime variable

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of code would be simpler for you. I assume you have more triples like (A,B,C), right? How would you like to inform what A or B should be selected for each C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose one of the overloaded functions, at least you have to tell compiler the argument types of the target function. So we can add them as type arguments of the template class `mixed_dispatch`

```
template < typename Tag, typename... Args >
class mixed_dispatch {
    std::function<void(Tag,Args...)> invoke;

public:
    // for overloaded functions
    mixed_dispatch( void(&f)(Tag,Args...) ) : invoke( f ) { }

    // for function objects
    template < typename F >
    mixed_dispatch( F&& f ) : invoke( std::forward<F>(f) ) { }

    void operator()( Args... args ) const {
        invoke( Tag(), args... );
    }
};
```

Now `mixed_dispatch` becomes a wrapper which helps you passing `Tag` objects to the target function. As you see, we need to change signature of target function(a bit works).

```
void fun_impl(A1, bool) { std::cout << "A1\n"; }
```

In client code, like `fun`:

```
template< typename T >
void fun( bool b, T )
{
    using dispatcher = mixed_dispatch<T,bool>;
    dispatcher d = fun_impl;
    d( b );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it answer any of your questions?

```
// traits types
struct A1 {}; struct B1 {};
struct A2 {}; struct B2 {};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct TypeSelector
{
    typedef T1 TTrue;
    typedef T2 TFalse;
};

typedef TypeSelector<A1, B1> C1;
typedef TypeSelector<A2, B2> C2;

// helpers
void fun_impl(bool, A1) { std::cout << "A1\n"; }
void fun_impl(bool, B1) { std::cout << "B1\n"; }
void fun_impl(bool, A2) { std::cout << "A2\n"; }
void fun_impl(bool, B2) { std::cout << "B2\n"; }

template<class TSel>
void fun_impl(bool b, TSel) { if(b) fun_impl(b, typename TSel::TTrue()); else fun_impl(b, typename TSel::TFalse()); }

template<typename T>
void fun(bool b, T t)
{
    // T = A, B, or C
    fun_impl(b, t);
}

int main()
{
    fun(true,  A1()); // "A1"
    fun(false, A1()); // "A1"
    fun(true,  B1()); // "B1"
    fun(false, B1()); // "B1"
    fun(true,  C1()); // "A1"
    fun(false, C1()); // "B1"
    fun(true,  C2()); // "A2"
    fun(false, C2()); // "B2"
}
```

Or you want to simplify the code in other "dimension"?

Comment: this gives me even more overloads for `fun_impl`! that makes it even worse

Comment: Ok, I assumed you have more (A,B,C) triples (ie (A1,B1,C1), (A2, B2, C2)), and my example shows eliminating one fun_impl in such a case. Now (after you edited the question) I see that was not your goal.